Jerky SVG Movement
The question IS:  What is causing the event.offsetX & event.offsetY to SOMETIMES have a value +/-10 than what they should be.  Things I have observed that affect this are:

Passing through certain areas of an SVG.
Preforming a console.log(event.offsetX) can remediate this depending on if it's performed before or after other lines.

I do not know why either of these should have any impact.  I have never experienced any other behavior like this.
The question IS NOT / answers ARE NOT:

Why am I deleting and recreating an element?  Both because I can, and this code is to just demonstrate the problem.
How can I perform this differently.  I am not looking for alternate solutions.  I know how to do things differently.  I am trying to understand what is causing the undesired results in THIS code.
My viewbox is not set to the same size as the SVG element and I need to use a certain preserveAspectRatio setting. No I do not. There is no requirement for either of these.  They are certainly allowed to be different.
My SVG pointer does not line up with the HTML cursor.  I know; that is not what I want it to do.  I do not need answers showing me how to convert a HTML point to a SVG point.  I know how to do this this is not what I am looking for.
I need to use getCTM()/getSreecCTM().  No I do not.  Those do not provide what I am looking to do, and are irrelevant to the question.
This is working for some people.  If you are getting some completely different error, I cannot help you with your device.
This is not an SVG animation problem.  Logging/debugging can show the offsetX & offsetY values sometimes have a value of +/-10 of what they should be.

I was working on an application to track movement in an SVG viewbox relative to the size of the SVG element itself.  The sample code below has been reduced to remove any extra functions, variables, calculations, etc. as much as possible to demonstrate just the problem.
When moving the mouse cursor across the SVG, the green (purple & yellow edits added per comments) pointer tracker its x & y positions by 10px each when moving through the approximate zones marked by the red bands.  Also moving left to right vs. right to left has slightly different trigger points.


const svg = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg.addEventListener('pointermove', event => {
    // console.log(event.offsetX);
    const id1 = 'pointer1';
    const id2 = 'pointer2';
    const id3 = 'pointer3';

    const pointerOld1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    if (pointerOld1) pointerOld1.remove();
    const pointerOld2 = document.getElementById(id2);
    if (pointerOld2) pointerOld2.remove();

    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;

    const pointerNew1 = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', id1);
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x * 0.25);
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y * 0.5);
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '15px');
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'green');
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5px');
    pointerNew1.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
    svg.append(pointerNew1);

    const point = new DOMPoint(x, y).matrixTransform(svg.getCTM().inverse());
    const pointerNew2 = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', id2);
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', point.x);
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', point.y);
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '15px');
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'purple');
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5px');
    pointerNew2.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
    svg.append(pointerNew2);

    const pointer3 = document.getElementById(id3);
    if (!pointer3) {
        const pointer3 = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', id3);
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '10px');
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'yellow');
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5px');
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
        svg.append(pointer3);
    }
    else {
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x * 0.25);
        pointer3.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y * 0.5);
    }

});
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="400" height="200"
    style="border: 2px solid;">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100px" y2="100" stroke="blue" />
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="blue" />
    <rect x="14" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="16" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="18" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="22" y="0" width="12" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="75" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="77" y="0" width="12" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
</svg>



I found some "work-arounds" including:

If I uncomment the console.log(event.offsetX); line, it performs fine.
If I move the x & y constant declarations before the if (pointerOld) pointerOld.remove(); line, it also works fine.

However, I am trying to understand why it is behaving like this in the first place?  Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug (in HTML/JavaScript/SVG/web browser/OS)?

@herrstrietzel No, I do that exactly for other purposes, but that is not what I am trying to do in this case.

@herrstrietzel I edited the code to show 2 pointer markers. 1) The original pointer - viewbox size relative to SVG sive. 2) An addition pointer tracking mouse pointer directly to entire SVG visible viewport area using the getCTM() method.  This jerky movement happens to bother both pointers.

Sorry for the misunderstanding but I still don't quite understand why you need to constantly remove and create a new Pointer instead of creating it only at the first mouse movement. See codepen

@Mister Jojo I know my view box is sizzed differently than the SVG itself.  Everyone is not understanding when I said, "SVG viewbox relative to the size of the SVG element itself".  these are allowed to be sized differently.  And yes, I have tried -50 (but also needed to change the x scale factor from .25 to .5 too).  But it seemed when I included an addition/subtraction math operation, the problem went away.  I'll qualify this as another 'work-around', but it does not help me understand why this problem is occuring.

@herrstrietzel the reason I have the remove is, when using touches I wanted the pointer(s) the be removed at the end.  I when I made the 'reduced' code to simplify as much as possible, that was left in there.  Your codepen code may work for me for a proper solution, but I'd still like to understand what is causing this jitter in the first place - to avoid it to future applications.

Not sure but removing and creating a svg element ~ 60 times per second could explain the jitter as it puts some load on the renderer

@herrstrietzel This is not processing 60x/sec. Only when the event is triggered. You can see this by adding a console.log() to the event. I added a pointer 3 which matches your codepen, but the problem still exists even to pointer 3, as there are still remove()s for the other two pointers.  But yes, remove()s seem to be throwing something off, as I mentioned in the "work-arounds".  The value of the event.offsetX & Y seem to change when using either before or after the remove - but only when the mouse is at certain positions.  It should not be behaving this way.

Maybe not 60fps but once you're moving the pointer you definitely evoke a massive amount of DOM tree manipulations. Why it's particularly jittery at certain positions - no clue. Nonetheless, if you see a jittery repaint/animation it usually indicates there are too expensive DOM manipulations occurring. Keep also in mind SVG manipulations are quite often not well optimized (e.g via gpu acceleration). So you can't expect a result as smooth as a native cursor or maybe a canvas approach.

JS note: you don't need to use setAttributeNS, you only need the namespace for creating SVG elements. But if you do use setAttributeNS, pass the namespace. Just have a const SVGNS = "...."; and then use that. Also note that your code currently throw Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "inverse", svg.getCTM() is null and your post does not talk about that: talk about that. Or fix it, of course.

@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Good to know about not needing to use setAttributeNS.  but the is outside the scope of my question and the answer I am looking for.  Also, your comment about using a const, is not relevant to the question.  As stated, this was a reduced code to show a few variables as possible for the purpose of presentation, not a production application. I am also unaware of Uncaught TypeError... message.  Not sure how I am supposed to talk about it.  Are you saying they is what is causing the problem I am experiencing?

That's why it was a comment, not an answer. As for the error: just run your code in your post right here, with dev tools open, and mouse over your SVG. Whether it's part of the problem or not is something you're going to have to figure out. If you can fix it, fix it, if you can't either remove the functionality that triggers it, or update your post to talk about it.

Please have a look at this codepen example: It seems like the jitter/offsets happen when cursor position coincides with the pointer circle element (becoming the event.target). You can see this effect more severe in Firefox. Apparently, the event object get messed up/reset after removing the pointer. A simple workaround could be to disable pointer events so the pointer element itself can't become the event.target.

@herrstrietzel looking at you codepen, at first I did not see any jitter in either SVG.  But the I move the const x & y lines to after the line with the remove(), and then it occur on the top SVG.  I also found some discrepancies in my edits, and there have been too many comments to follow, that I was thinking I should delete this post.  Yes, something if flaking out, I was just trying to understand why.  But I've spent too much time on this matter preventing other progress.

I assume you want getScreenCTM rather than getCTM

@Robert Longson No I do not.  Also, not relevant to the question.

First of all, like herrstrietzel write in the comment, the coordinate system for the SVG is different from the HTML page. Use the screenToSVG() function mentioned here.
Second, you don't need to create a new circle element on each event call back. Reuse the one that is already there.


const pointerMove = event => {
  let svg = event.target.closest('svg');
  let pointer = svg.querySelector('.pointer');

  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;
  let coordinates = screenToSVG(svg, x, y);
  
  pointer.setAttribute('cx', coordinates.x);
  pointer.setAttribute('cy',coordinates.y);
}

let svg1 = document.getElementById('svg1');
svg1.addEventListener('pointermove', pointerMove);

function screenToSVG(svg, screenX, screenY) {
   var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
    p.x = screenX;
    p.y = screenY;
    return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="400" height="200" style="border: 2pt solid;">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100px" y2="100" stroke="blue" />
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="blue" />
    <rect x="14" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="16" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="18" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="20" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="22" y="0" width="12" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="75" y="0" width="1" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="77" y="0" width="12" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <circle class="pointer" r="15" stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
</svg>




No no no no.......I said "SVG viewbox relative to the size of the SVG element itself".  Your solution is not my intent.  Also I edited my question to also include another pointer like you have shown, but I still experience the same problem.  I am trying to understand why the problem I am having is occurring.

@Adam Sassano: As explained: unnecessary DOM element creations/removals will always negatively impact performance resulting in jittery renderings. If you really need different cursor outlines for different events (e.g mouse vs. touch)  just change the appearance (e.g by CSS class toggling). Also "track movement in an SVG viewbox relative to the size of the SVG element itself" is in your example a slightly complicated way to say that screen/pointer coordinates are applied 1:1 to the SVG circle.

@herrstrietzel It's not just jitter in the rendering.  It you do debugging it shows the offesetX & Y change by +/1 10 each causing the jumping around.   I don't know how many times I need to say the same thing.  But again, 1) this occurs when passing through only certain area to the SVG. 2) This can be remediated by adding a console.log of an event property to the event.  The event properties should not change based on if there was a console.log of one of its properties.  And again, I'm not looking how to do things differently, I'm looking for an explanation as to what is occurring.

@herrstrietzel Also, it is not accurate to qualify DOM creations/removals as "unnecessary". It's also pretty ambiguous to say there will always negatively impact performance resulting in jittery renderings. If either of these things were true, we should get rid of JavaScript, and just use static webpages only. I have also shown where I can produce the jitter with a 1:1 html coordinate to svg vb coordinate. So the issue is not just my original "relative" mapping. And, no I am not looking for different events/class toggling/different solution. Those are all outside of the scope of the question.

@chrwahl Can you delete this answer as it DOES NOT the question?  The question is looking for an explanation of the results I am getting, not a different solution.  And the Answer DOES NOT match what I am trying to achieve as well.
